# Migrating Expression.inExpression with kotlin.IntArray from Mapbox Android v9 to v10

Tags: android, kotlin, mapbox, mapbox-android

I'm migrating an app from v9 of the Mapbox Android SDK to v10, and I'm running into an issue trying to update some code we're using to filter a layer's features using a Kotlin `IntArray`.

This worked for us in Mapbox Android v9: `Expression.inExpression(Expression.get("id"), Expression.literal(intArray))`

However, after updating the SDK to v10 I get an error: "None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied." It looks like `Expression.literal` supports passing a `List<Any>` in, but the function is marked internal. I think going with `Expression.ExpressionBuilder` may work, but I'm kind of flying blind and can't find any documentation on this.

How do I migrate this line of code to Mapbox v10?

`Expression.inExpression(Expression.get("id"), Expression.literal(intArray))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to accomplish the same functionality in v10 by passing an `Expression.ExpressionBuilder` block to `Expression.inExpression`:

```
Expression.inExpression {
  get("id")
  literal(ids)
}
```